# handle too many require in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, design-patterns

I'm writing a HTTP server with nodejs and express and I have a `db` module using in many other modules.

Is there a problem require this module in many many files?

Does too many requires cause memory leak?

Is it a better way like using global var?

my module is something like this :

```
module.exports = (function() {
    return {
        user : ...
    };
})();
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`require()` method *means* **load** and **cache** Javascript modules

You can use `require` as many times as required in your app, It won't be cause of memory leak, Reason when you `require` a module in a file its loaded and cached and when you `require` same module in another file again it comes from cache(same reference in other words) so Its actually one time required (loaded) and the module that controls `loading`, `compiling`, and `caching` resides in `module.js`

Further details on [MODULE](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) and [Tutorial](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/)

Comment: was answer helpful for you?